# Remove empty xmlns created by serializer

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have an object generated by an "Add service reference..." operation and I am manually serializing it with a generic serializer I wrote.

My problem is that the data contract has some internal objects.

The serializer adds an empty namespace atribute to the starting tag of the internal objects. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Why is that a problem? If the elements are in the default namespace, then `xmlns=""` is correct.

Comment: xmlns="" might be correct, but I don't have control of the WS receiving this, and it will not work with them. Any way to remove them?

Comment: If xmlns="" breaks the code reading your XML, then it is badly broken and has a very bad bug that needs to be fixed. It is failing to read some basic, correct XML. Be certain to be a good neighbor and tell the owners of that code that they should fix it to handle the default namespace.

Comment: What do you mean by, "a generic serializer I wrote"?  If it is a custom serializer then didn't you define its behaviour yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about making your internal objects belong to the same namespace as the root? That way, it would be correct to omit the `xmlns` declaration from the descendants. You can use the `[assembly: ContractNamespace]` attribute to override the namespace for all contracts in your assembly. Refer to [Data Contract Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx) for an example.

**Edit**: An elaboration with some examples below.

Suppose you’re constructing an XML document manually, and don’t specify a namespace for any of your elements.

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Book",
        new XElement("Title", "Animal Farm"),
        new XElement("Author", "George Orwell"),
        new XElement("Publisher",
            new XElement("Name", "Secker and Warburg"),
            new XElement("Location", "London"),
            new XElement("Founded", 1910))));
return xmlDocument.ToString();
```

The generated XML would, as expected, be void of namespace declarations:

```
<Book>
  <Title>Animal Farm</Title>
  <Author>George Orwell</Author>
  <Publisher>
    <Name>Secker and Warburg</Name>
    <Location>London</Location>
    <Founded>1910</Founded>
  </Publisher>
</Book>
```

If, however, you specify a namespace just for your root element, then all child elements must explicitly revert out of that default namespace, using the `xml=""` declaration. Per the [Namespace Defaulting](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) rules:

> The scope of a default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself.

Thus, the following code (having a namespace specified for the root element)…

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Book",
        new XElement("Title", "Animal Farm"),
        new XElement("Author", "George Orwell"),
        new XElement("Publisher",
            new XElement("Name", "Secker and Warburg"),
            new XElement("Location", "London"),
            new XElement("Founded", 1910))));
return xmlDocument.ToString();
```

…would give the following XML:

```
<Book xmlns="http://example.com/library">
  <Title xmlns="">Animal Farm</Title>
  <Author xmlns="">George Orwell</Author>
  <Publisher xmlns="">
    <Name>Secker and Warburg</Name>
    <Location>London</Location>
    <Founded>1910</Founded>
  </Publisher>
</Book>
```

Note how the children of the `<Publisher>` element do not need to revert out of the root’s namespace, since they inherit the “no namespace” declaration from their parent.

To eliminate the `xmlns=""` declarations, we could, for the sake of the demonstration, assign the same namespace to all descendants:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Book",
        new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Title", "Animal Farm"),
        new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Author", "George Orwell"),
        new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Publisher",
            new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Name", "Secker and Warburg"),
            new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Location", "London"),
            new XElement("{http://example.com/library}Founded", 1910))));
return xmlDocument.ToString();
```

This would give an XML document with the namespace declared in just the root (and implicitly inherited in all descendants):

```
<Book xmlns="http://example.com/library">
  <Title>Animal Farm</Title>
  <Author>George Orwell</Author>
  <Publisher>
    <Name>Secker and Warburg</Name>
    <Location>London</Location>
    <Founded>1910</Founded>
  </Publisher>
</Book>
```

To mimic your scenario involving a web service, we can create the following WCF service.

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Publisher
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public short Founded { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ILibraryService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Book GetBook();
}

public class LibraryService : ILibraryService
{
    public Book GetBook()
    {
        return new Book
        {
            Title = "Animal Farm",
            Author = "George Orwell",
            Publisher = new Publisher
            {
                Name = "Secker and Warburg",
                Location = "London",
                Founded = 1910,
            }
        };
    }
}
```

We add a service reference to the above service in our client application, consume its operation, and serialize the result whilst enclosing it in a root `Books` element having an explicit namespace:

```
using (var libraryClient = new LibraryServiceReference.LibraryServiceClient())
{
    var book = libraryClient.GetBook();

    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Books", "http://example.com/library");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(book.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, book);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

In this case, the inner element `Book` contains an `xmlns=""` declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Books xmlns="http://example.com/library">
  <Book xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns="">
    <ExtensionData />
    <Author>George Orwell</Author>
    <Publisher>
      <ExtensionData />
      <Founded>1910</Founded>
      <Location>London</Location>
      <Name>Secker and Warburg</Name>
    </Publisher>
    <Title>Animal Farm</Title>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

As explained above, this `xmlns=""` can be eliminated by setting the `Book` element’s namespace (and that of its descendants) to correspond to the root’s. For the `XmlSerializer` class, the default namespace for all elements can be specified through the second parameter to its constructor. (The actual technique would vary depending on which serialization strategy you’re using.)

```
using (var libraryClient = new LibraryServiceReference.LibraryServiceClient())
{
    var book = libraryClient.GetBook();

    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Books", "http://example.com/library");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(book.GetType(), "http://example.com/library");
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, book);
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

And that would give the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Books xmlns="http://example.com/library">
  <Book xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ExtensionData />
    <Author>George Orwell</Author>
    <Publisher>
      <ExtensionData />
      <Founded>1910</Founded>
      <Location>London</Location>
      <Name>Secker and Warburg</Name>
    </Publisher>
    <Title>Animal Farm</Title>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: I ended up using the data contract serializer instead of XmlSerializer, which made it work out-of-the-box, but thank you very much for the answer. Bounty earned.

Comment: Thanks! :-) I was going to mention `DataContractSerializer`, but I (mistakenly) assumed that the service itself was declaring empty (or incorrect) namespaces for its data contracts (e.g. `[DataContract(Namespace="")]`), which is not easy to circumvent on the client side with that serializer. `XmlSerializer` ignores the namespaces declared on the data contracts, allowing you to substitute your own. Anyway, glad you found a simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little off-topic and might not apply if you're using `[DataContract]`. Rather, this applies to proxy code generated from a WSDL (in an interop environment with a java endpoint, we've been told the xmlns="" is invalid). So I'm putting it out there in case it helps.

The `XmlElementAttribute.Form` property can cause xmlns="" to be output for child members in the WCF request when set to `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified`.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string MyProperty {
     get; set;
}
```

which produces something along the lines of

```
<MyObject xmlns="http://some.namespance">
   <MyProperty xmlns="">My value goes here</MyProperty>
</MyObject>
```

Setting it to `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.None` (which is the default value) means it won't output the "unqualified" namespace attribute.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.None)]
public string MyProperty {
    get; set;
}
```

which produces this:

```
<MyObject xmlns="http://some.namespance">
   <MyProperty>My value goes here</MyProperty>
</MyObject>
```

I'm not sure if you can change this behaviour while importing the wsdl reference, or perhaps the wsdl should have been changed, but I ended up editing the generated proxy code directly (which definitely isn't ideal), but achieved my immediate goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the serializer you can always add a null namespace to ensure the xmlns is omitted from the output XML. For instance:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(target.GetType()); 
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); 
ns.Add("",""); 
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, target, ns);
```

Best regards,

Comment: I tried that, but it remove the xmlns from all the elements. I need the root to still have the xmlns (which is not empty).