# How do I remove the xmlns="" attribute added to newly created XElement nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

When I add new nodes to the root of a node that has a namespace defined, subsequent nodes added all receive xmlns="" attached to to them. This is the code that shows my problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var xdoc = new XDocument();
    var shipmentRoot = new XElement("{someNS}Shipment");

    var newElement = new XElement("ContainerCollection", new XElement("Container", new XElement("ContainerNumber", "42")));
    newElement.SetAttributeValue("Content", "Partial");

    shipmentRoot.Add(newElement);
    xdoc.Add(shipmentRoot);
    xdoc.Dump();

}
```

Generates this XML:

```
<Shipment xmlns="someNS">
  <ContainerCollection Content="Partial" xmlns="">
    <Container>
      <ContainerNumber>42</ContainerNumber>
    </Container>
  </ContainerCollection>
</Shipment>
```

My desired XML would be:

```
<Shipment xmlns="someNS">
  <ContainerCollection Content="Partial">
    <Container>
      <ContainerNumber>42</ContainerNumber>
    </Container>
  </ContainerCollection>
</Shipment>
```

Comment: Just create the elements in the `someNS` namespace. I'm sure this is a duplicate...

Comment: Your desired output indicates all elements should be in `someNS` - to do this, you'll need to add `ContainerCollection`, `Container` et al to `someNs` as well?

Answer (score 1):

While I suspect this is a duplicate, I can't easily find it. The problem is that in your desired XML, the `ContainerCollection`, `Container` and `ContainerNumber` elements are in the namespace `"someNS"` as that is the default inherited from their `Shipment` ancestor... but you're creating elements with an *empty* namespace. The fix is just to create them with the right namespace:

```
// I prefer this over using {someNS}Shipment, personally. YMMV.
XNamespace ns = "someNS";
var shipmentRoot = new XElement(ns + "Shipment");

var newElement = new XElement(ns + "ContainerCollection",
     new XElement(ns + "Container",
         new XElement(ns + "ContainerNumber", "42")));
newElement.SetAttributeValue("Content", "Partial");
```

Comment: This is what I needed. After further searching I found the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822859/remove-empty-xmlns-created-by-serializer

Comment: @VictorioBerra: Well that's talking about the XML serializer - not really a duplicate, IMO. I'm sure there are others though :)

Comment: I will say after implementing this solution it sucks to have to add ns + to every single one of my nodes.

Comment: You don't need to set the "Content" attribute separately. You can pass an XAttribute in the functional construction.

Comment: @anphu: Sure, but I was implementing a minimal change to the OP's original code.